# javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ipfs

I have my constructor like below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
        ipfsHash: '', 
        web3: null, 
        buffer: null,
        account: null
    };
    this.captureFile = this.captureFile.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

Then I have:

```
this.simpleStorageInstance.set(result[0].hash, { from: this.state.account}).then((r) => {
    return this.setState({ipfsHash: result[0].hash })
    console.log('ipfsHash', this.state.ipfsHash)  
})
```

console reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `then i have` Where? Looks like there's no calling context of whatever that function is

Comment: can you show how do you declare `simpleStorageInstance`?

Comment: `simpleStorageInstance` is undefined

Answer (score -1):

Considering that the only `set` call in your code happens on `this.simpleStorageInstance` and assignment to `this.simpleStorageInstance` is nowhere to be found in you constructor's code, I would say you forgot to properly set this property's value.